# Can't get usbmon to work

Tags: usb-drive

I'm trying to use `usbmon` but `modprobe usbmon` does not work.

The error is

> FATAL: Module usbmon not found

I'm using kernel version `2.6.31-23-generic-pae` do I need to recompile the kernel? Is there another way to monitor usb traffic?

Also is there a known bug in usb driver?  At the app level I at times fail to receive a packet. I am using `libusb 1.0` and it's not reporting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The stock kernel is configured with `CONFIG_USB_MON=y`, which means that it's a built-in feature, so you don't need to load any module before using the usbmon functionality.

Comment: Thanx, for the reply.  Got it going...it seems libusb has a problem with timeouts when using libusb_interrupt_transfer call...